# How to crop out all black pixels in a complex shaped image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I have an image of a snake. The snake is curved, of course, so I want to extract the snake from the image.

The background is all black, so I think this should be relatively straight forward. My attempt right now doesn't get close enough. I was hoping to trace around the curve, not just throw an arbitrary box around the snake. Is this possible?

This is what I have:

```
 bw = im2bw(test, graythresh(test));
 [row, col] = find(bw);
 topLeftRow = min(row);
 topLeftCol = min(col);
 bottomRightRow = max(row);
 bottomRightCol = max(col);
 maskedImage = bsxfun(@times, test, cast(bw, class(test)));
 extractedSnake = maskedImage(topLeftRow:bottomRightRow, topLeftCol:bottomRightCol, :);


  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you add the image?

Comment: Sure, just did.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply detect edges and dilate the image. The parameters can be adjusted for best result.

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('blkil.jpg'));

figure,
subplot(1,4,1)
imshow(im)
title('Original')

% Detect edges
subplot(1,4,2)
BW1 = edge(im,'Canny');
imshow(BW1)
title('Edges')

% Dilate
subplot(1,4,3)
se = strel('disk',12);
BW2 = imdilate(BW1,se);
imshow(BW2)
title('Dilated')

% Detect resulting edges
subplot(1,4,4)
BW3 = edge(BW2,'Canny');
imshow(BW3)
title('Result shape')
```

[image]

Comment: Does Matlab allow you to actually extract the shape of the snake?

Comment: Yes, you can use another edge operation in the end result of my code and get the border lines of the snake

Comment: Would this allow the image to not actually be a box?

Comment: What do you mean by box?

Comment: I guess I am just wondering if I can extract the snake image itself and get the proper shape of that.

Comment: I updated the code, let me know if that's what you are trying to get. It looks better when zoomed in MATLAB.